# Html.RenderAction MVC areas routing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am attempting to render a partial view within the main Shared **_Layout.chtml** file of my ASP.net MVC 4 project.  This simple code is shown below

```
@{Html.RenderAction("UserMenu", "MyController");}
```

This all works fine when the user is within the root of the site.  However, my project also includes an 'Area' called 'Customers'.

When the user navigates to anywhere within the 'Customers' area of my site an exception occurs on the line above and the debugger basically tells me it cannot find the controller

```
"The controller for path '/Customers/CustomersHome' was not found or does not implement IController."
```

The same exception occurs if I use **Html.RenderPartial**

Interestingly, if I swap out **Html.RenderAction** for **Html.Action**, this exception does not occur (although obviously nothing is rendered).

Does anyone know a way round this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried setting the area to a null string?

```
@{Html.RenderAction("UserMenu", "MyController", new { area="" });}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!  It's strange that you don't have to set the area to a null string with the likes of Html.RenderAction.

Comment: Happened to me as well. Had a host controller, with the view in another DLL and the Area + Action in a third DLL. When trying with the proper area="AreaName" it kept popping up an error exactly like yours. With an empty area, it works. Weird ...